# Why doesn't my addTarget's function on button work?

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing some function to be called once a button is tapped but the function's body doesn't get called.
Here is my code which demonstrates what I need to do

```
let editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Edit Profile", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditProfileOrFollow), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    @objc func handleEditProfileOrFollow () {
        print("Execute edit profile or follow ")
    }
```

and this is what happens in my init

```
addSubview(editProfileFollowButton)
        editProfileFollowButton.setAnchor(top: postsLabel.bottomAnchor, left: postsLabel.leftAnchor, right: followingLabel.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, paddingTop: 2, height: 34, width: 0)
    }
```

PS: setAnchor is a function that I created to set up the constraints of the view programmatically

Comment: Can you show the code that adds the button to the view hierarchy.

Comment: addTarget won’t retain the receiver. Are you sure that self is not deallocated?

Comment: @WernerAltewischer May you please explain more? is that a memory thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code you have shown, the most obvious thing is your use of `let`

When building variables with actions using a closure style, I have always been under the impression that you should use a `lazy var` instantiation. This is used (I believe) as `self` is not known at compile time.

```
lazy var editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Edit Profile", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditProfileOrFollow), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    @objc func handleEditProfileOrFollow () {
        print("Execute edit profile or follow ")
    }
```

The use of `lazy var` is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. ([Source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html))

Comment: Thank you so much , this actually worked for me , but I still don't get the idea why using lazy var would solve the problem here? I know what is lazy var and when to use it but it was way far from my mind to use it here in this scenario as I see that there is no use of it in such situation

Comment: I think it has to do with you adding a self as a target to the button, in a closure. If you had done it after instantiation, in the init call. I think it would be fine. I do the same with collectionView/tableView. If it worked, can you mark the answer as correct :P

Comment: I promise I will upvote your answer once I get the reputation for doing so :D

Comment: To explain what is happening: The function you use to define the value of a `let` does not have access to the class at all (the ViewController in this case).The `self` inside that function is not the VC, Try adding `print("self: \(String(describing: self))")` inside it.  The reason is: there is no VC at all yet.

Comment: When you make it a lazy var, there is a VC, and self refers to it.